# Conditional cumulative subtraction

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr, cumsum

This is what my data.table looks like:

```
library(data.table)
dt <- fread('
   Year      Total      Shares  Balance
   2017        10        1       10
   2016        12        2        9 
   2015        10        2        7
   2014        10        3        6
   2013        10        NA       3
')
```

**`Balance*`* is my desired column. I am trying to find the cumulative subtractions by taking the first value of `Total` which is 10(it should also be the first value of `Balance` field) and then cumulatively subtracting values in `Shares`. So the second value is `10-1 =9` and the third value is `9-2 = 7` and such. There is one condition, if the `Year` is 2014, then subtract the `Shares` value after dividing it by `2`. so the fourth value is `7-(2/2)=6` and the fifth value is `6-3=3`. I want to end the calc as of the last row.

My attempt is:

```
dt[, Balance:= ifelse( Year == 2014, cumsum(Total[1]-Shares/2), cumsum(Total[1] - Shares))]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method.

```
dt[, Balance2 := Total[1] - cumsum(shift(Shares * (1 - (0.5 *(Year == 2015))), fill=0))]
```

`shift` is used to create a lag variable, and the first element is filled with 0, using `fill=0`. The other elements are calculated as `Shares * (1 - (0.5 *(Year == 2015)))` which return Shares except when `Years == 2015`, in which case `Shares * 0.5` is returned.

which returns

```
dt
   Year Total Shares Balance Balance2
1: 2017    10      1      10       10
2: 2016    12      2       9        9
3: 2015    10      2       7        7
4: 2014    10      3       6        6
5: 2013    10     NA       3        3
```

Answer (score 1):

FWIW, I wanted to provide a functional alternative that would allow for more flexible calculations in the cumulative differences, indexing, etc. I also have read in the data with `read.table`.

```
dt <- read.table(header=TRUE, text='
   Year      Total      Shares  Balance
            2017        10        1       10
            2016        12        2        9 
            2015        10        2        7
            2014        10        3        6
            2013        10        NA       3
            ')

makeNewBalance <- function(dt) {
    output <- NULL
    for (i in 1:nrow(dt)) {
        if (i==1) {
            output[i] <- dt$Total[i]
        } else {
            output[i] <- output[i-1] - as.integer(ifelse(dt$Year[i]==2014, 
                                                         dt$Shares[i-1]/2, 
                                                         dt$Shares[i-1]))
        }
    }
    return(output)
}

dt$NewBalance <- makeNewBalance(dt)
```

which also returns

```
> dt
  Year Total Shares Balance NewBalance
1 2017    10      1      10         10
2 2016    12      2       9          9
3 2015    10      2       7          7
4 2014    10      3       6          6
5 2013    10     NA       3          3
```